# Wistia multiple embed videos in single page quality and speed options not working

Tags: javascript, html5-video, wistia

I am trying to add wistia multiple video embed code in single page.
The sample scripts are as below. Both videos are different.

```
<script src=https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/1234.jsonp async></script><script src=https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js async></script><div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;"><div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_1234 videoFoam=true" style="height:100%;position:relative;width:100%"><div class="wistia_swatch" style="height:100%;left:0;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;transition:opacity 200ms;width:100%;"><img src=https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/1234/swatch style="filter:blur(5px);height:100%;object-fit:contain;width:100%;" alt="" aria-hidden="true" onload="this.parentNode.style.opacity=1;" /></div></div></div></div>
<script src=https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/5678.jsonp async></script><script src=https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js async></script><div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;"><div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_5678 videoFoam=true" style="height:100%;position:relative;width:100%"><div class="wistia_swatch" style="height:100%;left:0;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;transition:opacity 200ms;width:100%;"><img src=https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/5678/swatch style="filter:blur(5px);height:100%;object-fit:contain;width:100%;" alt="" aria-hidden="true" onload="this.parentNode.style.opacity=1;" /></div></div></div></div>
```

Both video works good but the problem is it only allows to change video quality and speed options in first video only. In second video the options are visible but not working.
I have also tried adding E-v1.js only once but still same issue.
Not sure what am I doing wrong here I have just added embeded code I got from wistia in my html page. Any one has any idea about this?